# download enterprise GitHub asset using HTML anchor <a> or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, github

I am attempting to link directly to an asset file in a way that any user can download the asset without needing to log in.

I've created an access token, `abcd1234`.

I've attempted to link to the release by id in the html, which does not work

```html
<a href="https://git.myCompany.com/api/v3/repos/myOrg/myRepo/releases/assets/123?access_token=abcd1234" download="file.exe" type="application/octet-stream">
    Download
</a>
```

I've also attempted to link directly to the resource, which prompts a user login screen (undesirable)

```html
<a download href="https://git.myCompany.com/myOrg/myRepo/releases/download/v1.0/myApp-1.0.exe?access_token=abcd1234">
    Download
</a>
```

And I have also attempted handling the download in `js`, which I haven't been able to manage.

```html
<a download onclick="downloadAsset()">
    Download
</a>
```

```
window.downloadAsset = function () {
    const url = 'https://git.myCompany.com/api/v3/repos/myOrg/myRepo/releases/assets/123';

    const options = {
        headers: { 
            Authorization: 'token abcd1234',
            Accept: 'application/octet-stream'
        }
    };

    fetch(url, options)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(data => {
            // Save blob data as file
        });
};
```

#### How can this be done without a back end proxy?

The response from the `fetch` call results in a 302 that I can click on in the browser console and the file begins to download, but it is blocked due to CORS from github, despite the authentication header.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable CORS inside `fetch` sentence:

```
window.downloadAsset = function () {
    const url = 'https://git.myCompany.com/api/v3/repos/myOrg/myRepo/releases/assets/123';

    const options = {
        headers: { 
            Authorization: 'token abcd1234',
            Accept: 'application/octet-stream'
        }, 
        method: 'get', 
        mode: 'no-cors'
    };

    fetch(url, options)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(data => {
            // Save blob data as file
        });
};
```

Also, you can try accept CORS inside fetch:

```
window.downloadAsset = function () {
    const url = 'https://git.myCompany.com/api/v3/repos/myOrg/myRepo/releases/assets/123';

    const options = {
        headers: { 
            Authorization: 'token abcd1234',
            Accept: 'application/octet-stream'
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
        }, 
        method: 'get', 
        mode: 'cors'
    };

    fetch(url, options)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(data => {
            // Save blob data as file
        });
};
```

Other way: You can try to add this PHP code a the beginnig of your HTML file for accepting cross origins:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

Anyway the best option is accepting CORS in the back end

---

Two possibles solutions for back-end are:

- **If you are using node.js:** node.js server file: response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' })
- **If you are using Apache**: In Settings (as the first option), add this directive: Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin * .